# What is the correct way to upgrade the versions of Haskell programs installed on /usr/bin?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-platform, cabal-install

I have the 3.0.1 version of [Alex](http://www.haskell.org/alex/) installed on my `/usr/bin`. I think the Haskell Platform originally put it there (although I'm not 100% sure...).

Unfortunately, version 3.0.1 is [bugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514316/haskell-alex-error-in-wrapper-template) so I need to upgrade it to 3.0.5. I tried using cabal to install the latest version of Alex but `cabal install alex-3.0.5` it installed the executable on `.cabal/bin` over on my home folder instead of on `/usr/bin`

**Do I just manually copy the executable to `/usr/bin`?** (that sound like a lot of trouble to do all the time)

**Do I change my PATH environment variable so that `.cabal/bin` comes before `/usr/bin`?** (I'm afraid that an "ls" executable or similar over on the cabal folder might end up messing up my system)

**Or is there a simpler way to go at it in general?**

Comment: Changing PATH so that `/.cabal/bin` is looked first is the best option. As os specific package manager usually puts up packages in `/usr/bin` so you shouldn't fiddle with it directly.

Comment: @Satvik: Ive had people telling me that you shouldnt put your stuff before /bin and /usr/bin on the PATH variable. Are you sure?

Comment: You shouldn't have installed alex in `/usr/bin` in the first place. The best way which I find is to install ghc and then install rest of the things using cabal. I know it came with the haskell platform but it also binds you to wait for the next release to update packages. I dont see any harm in the case for putting `.cabal/bin` before `/usr/bin`.

Comment: @missingno The reason you're not supposed to do that, as far as I can see, is if you accidentally create an executable called e.g. `vim` in one of the other directories you are a little screwed, but then you can always explicitly refer to `/usr/bin/vim` if you need to when you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second though, putting /.cabal/bin in front of /usr/bin in the PATH is simpler and is what most people do already.

Its also not a big deal since only cabal will put files in .cabal/bin so it should be predictable and with little risk of overwriting stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I want to first point out the layout that works well for me, and then suggest how you might proceed in your particular situation.

## What works well for me

In general, I think that a better layout is to have the following search path:

1. directories with important non-Haskell related binaries
2. directory that `cabal install` installs to
3. directory that binaries from the Haskell platform are in

This way, you can use `cabal install` to update binaries from the Haskell platform, but they cannot accidently shadow some non-Haskell related binary.

(On my Windows machine, this layout is easy to achieve, because the binaries from the Haskell platform are installed in a separate directory by default. So I just manually adapt the search path and that's it. I don't know how to achieve it on other platforms).

## Suggestion for your particular situation

In your specific situation with the Haskell platform binaries already installed together with the non-Haskell related binaries, maybe you can use the following layout for the search path:

1. directory containing links to some of the binaries in 3
2. directory with important non-Haskell related binaries and Haskell platform binaries
3. directory that `cabal install` installs to.

This way, binaries from `cabal install` cannot accidently shadow the important stuff in 2. But if you decide you want to shadow something form the Haskell platform, you can manually add a link to 1. If it's a soft link, I think you only have to do that once per program name, and then you can call `cabal install` for that program to update it. You could even look up what executables are bundled with the Haskell platform and do that once and for all.

Comment: An extra directory with softlinks is a great idea. Thanks!